Electrolysis of concentrated Sulfuric acid
While studying electrolysis, I came across the oxidation reaction of SO₄²⁻ where it oxidizes into S₂O₈^(2-). I don't understand why it prefers to dimerize and form S₂O₈^(2-) instead of just staying in the SO₄ state. Can someone please explain?

Assuming you meant $\ce{S2O8^2-}$ and not some $\ce{S2O8} (?),$ https://doi.org/10.1149%2F2.1161811jes should provide some insight. Not sure what reduction of sulfate ion you are talking about in title, though, and why some words are randomly capitalized.

The ion $\ce{SO4^{2-}}$ is not reduced in this electrolysis. On the contrary, it is oxidized into $\ce{S2O8^{2-}}$.

thank you for the correction!

This question is similar to: Can sulfuric acid itself be electrolysed?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
